# how to return documents which are contains the specific keywords in the keys from mongodb mlab in python flask

Tags: python, json, mongodb, flask, mlab

I have this collection in mongodb.
my collection:

```
 {
"_id": "5ad2079019551a2108588add",
"brand_name": "MAZOLA LIZA"
"name":"pyd"
 }

{
"_id": "5ad2079019551a2108588adf",
"brand_name": "MAZcara"
"name":"rahul"  
}
{
"_id": "5ad2079019551a2108588agf",
"brand_name": jk LIZA"
"name":"qa" 
}
```

My desired output:

```
{
"_id": "5ad2079019551a2108588add",
"brand_name": "MAZOLA LIZA"
"name":"pyd"
 }

{
"_id": "5ad2079019551a2108588adf",
"brand_name": "MAZcara"
"name":"rahul"  
}
```

I am trying to get the documents which are contains `MOZ in "brand_name"`

I am using flask_pymongo for this.

ill send this MOZ using flask method. (method/MOZ)

my code is,

```
@app.route('/framework/<name>', methods=['GET'])
def get_one_framework(name):
    framework = mongo.db.offers
    for q in framework.find({"product": {"$regex":"*."+ name+".*"}}):
        print(q)
```

its not printing any records, but i have matching records

Comment: You could use `"$regex"` and search for a regex string instead.

Comment: @chridam, this is totally different, I am trying in flask application.

Comment: The solution is not different, in fact it is `for q in framework.find({"brand_name": rgx }):` where `rgx` is initialised as `import re
rgx = re.compile('^' + re.escape(name))`. Check the other marked dupe answer.

Comment: Please update your question with what you have tried and the results you are getting.

Comment: do i need to change any index in mlab

Comment: edited my question, please check

Comment: @pyd the solution is easy. You have uppercase some thing in your database so you should run a `case insensitive` query. like this:

`framework.find({"brand_name": {"$regex":"*."+ name+".*", '$options': 'i'}})`

Comment: yes it worked with ` {"$regex":name, '$options': 'i'}`without the dot, is there any difference between with and without dots

Comment: it depends on the regex you want to apply. if you need more complex regex and more strict you should try different kind of patterns. for your case probably is enough with the dots.